# PHP date formatting issue

Tags: php, date, format

This PHP statement  `date('Y-m-d',1281394800)` returns different values in different servers.  One gives me `2010-08-09` and the other `2010-08-10`.  Could someone please help explain?

Comment: have you checked the timezone?

Comment: I would imagine it's a timezone thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if you still get different results:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d',1281394800);
```

If you get exactly the same results across servers, you can set the timezone to the one you want. For more information:

[date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

[List of Supported Timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.  I havent been keen on the time zone until it bit me here!  Thanks for all who responded about the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Are the servers in (or configured with) different timezones?

`date()`'s output is timezone-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Set the time zone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d',1281394800);
```

> date_default_timezone_set  —  Sets the
>   default timezone used by all date/time
>   functions in a script

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
- [List of Supported Timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)